# Class row com imagem

Tags: classes, css

Estou tentando colocar em uma linha três colunas, onde a primeira terá uma imagem e as demais devem ter o texto alinhado abaixo.

```html
<div class="row" style="background-color: #ffffff">
  <div class="col-md-2"><img src="../images/1.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="col-md-8">Empresa</div>
  <div class="col-md-2" style="text-align: right; vertical-align: text-bottom">Usuário</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pensou em usar um `table`?

```html
<div class="row" style="background-color: #ffffff">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><img width="100" src="http://www.rd.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2016/04/09-vets-wont-tell-dog-plays-park.jpg" /></td>
      <td>Empresa</td>
      <td>Usuário</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```